# My serializer is returning index instead of the actual fields

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am new to Django and I have been trying to serialize my model object called `MoviesCategories`.

```
class MoviesCategories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

There is also a `Movie` model that is as follows

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=False)
    thumbnail = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=False)
    source_url = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)
    duration = models.TimeField(default=timedelta(hours=2))
    added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(MoviesCategories, related_name="movies", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('added_on',)
```

My `MoviesCategoriesSerializer` looks like this

```
class MoviesCategoriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MoviesCategories
        fields = ('name', 'movies')
```

What I am getting from this serializer when I do 
`MoviesCategoriesSerializer(MoviesCategories.objects.first()).data`
is
`{'movies': [1, 2], 'name': 'Animations'}`

 I expect to get the fields of the movies too. I have created a `MovieSerializer`

`class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('name', 'thumbnail', 'source_url', 'duration')`

But I have no Idea on how to link the two such that 
`MoviesCategoriesSerializer(MoviesCategories.objects.first()).data`
returns me all movies in the first category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `MovieSerializer` as `MoviesCategoriesSerializer` field:

```
class MoviesCategoriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movies = MovieSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = MoviesCategories
        fields = ('name', 'movies')
```

See details [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).